# Suppress duplicate messages in rsyslog?

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

Is there a way to configure rsyslog to suppress identical duplicate messages?

In certain situations (often hardware failures) my syslog can grow to 100 MB or more due to repeated messages every quarter-second or so.

Comment: which version of rsyslog are you running?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See the [`$RepeatedMsgReduction`](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/action/rsconf1_repeatedmsgreduction.html) config switch, which turns such duplicate messages into one by logging *"Last line repeated n times"*.  You can also discard [unwanted messages](http://rsyslog.com/discarding-unwanted-messages/).